# Looking for a detailed example project for GWT with current MVP implementation

Tags: gwt

I like to start a new project with gwt, 2 years ago I worked with gwt but since then a lot has changed. Now it would be great if there is a sample project which includes the current best practices of an gwt application. I searched around but found only older ones, I am interested in MVP, places, history, uibinder etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

1. You can browse official samples, such as the [expenses sample app](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/expenses%253Fstate%253Dclosed), which makes use of MVP.
2. You can use [Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo/) to generate a GWT app that uses MVP architecture for you.  However, be aware that Roo generates complex code with a steep learning curve.
3. You can search community projects for those that use MVP
4. Instead of official GWT MVP, which doesn't support nested presenters (crucial for larger projects, IMO), you can use other MVP solutions, such as [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/)

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised it hasn't been mentioned yet: GWT's own sample [MobileWebApp](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp). It has all the GWT application elements you're looking for, as well as dependency injection with [GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/). Furthermore, it features a neat way of using deferred binding to select views for different screen form factors: desktop, tablet or smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this open source project written in GWT best practices (MVP, GIN, unit testing and others) http://james.apache.org/hupa/